# How to append a "/*" to the end of a variable with spaces and glob it?

Tags: bash, quoting, wildcards, variable

If I have a directory `wibble`, the following command does what I want:

```
WIBBLE=wibble
wc $WIBBLE/*
```

If I have a directory `foo bar`, the following command does what I want:

```
wc foo\ bar/*
```

But this doesn't do what I want

```
FOO="foo bar"
wc $FOO/*
```

I get:

```
wc: foo: No such file or directory
wc: bar/*: No such file or directory
```

I've tried everything I could find here, but nothing wants to work for me! What am I missing? I do not want a solution using `for` as I want to pipe the output from `wc` to other commands.

---

Examining the dup, this works:

```
FOO="foo bar"
BAR=("$FOO"/*)
wc "${BAR[@]}"
```

My question now becomes "Can I avoid the intermediate variable?". This just prints the straightforward expansion:

```
FOO="foo bar"
wc "("$FOO"/*)[@]"
```

Comment: If you have a completely new question. Please feel free to ask it with all information necessary. Doing edit that changes completly the scope of your question invalidate answer and the whole point of a Q&A site.

Comment: `FOO="foo bar"` ; `wc "${FOO}"/*` should skip the intermediate variable